# How to pass CallingMemberName to custom logging provider

Tags: c#, logging

Using ASP.NET Core and implementing my own console logging provider with ILogging and ILoggingProvider as I want to pass the name of the calling function to the logger as part of the log record as well as date/time stamp.

The best way to retrieve the name of the calling function is to use [CallerMemberName] attribute in the function parameters, however as I'm trying to keep to the standard logging pattern and inheriting the ILogger interface I can't work out how to overload any of the Log method calls to use an additional function parameter to add the CallerMemberName attribute.

Here is the code in Main:

```
public class Program
{
    static ILogger Logger { get; } = ApplicationLogging.CreateLogger<Program>();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         ApplicationLogging.Logger.AddMyLogger();
         Program.Logger.LogInformation("Test log");
    ...
    }
 }
```

Here is my custom logging provider

```
// Setup logging for all classes to use
public static class ApplicationLogging
{
    public static ILoggerFactory Logger { get; } = new LoggerFactory();
    public static ILogger CreateLogger<T>() =>
    Logger.CreateLogger<T>();
}

public static class MyLoggerProviderExtensions
{
    public static ILoggerFactory AddMyLogger(this ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddProvider(new MyLoggerProvider());
        return loggerFactory;
    }
}


public class MyLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    public MyLoggerProvider()
    {
    }

public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return new MyLogger();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class MyLogger : ILogger
{
    public MyLogger()
    {
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-20} {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"), " [NEED_CALLING_METHOD_NAME_HERE]", state);
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return new NoopDisposable();
    }

    private class NoopDisposable : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If I add CallerMemberName to the Log method call then I'm not implementing as per the interface and it won't compile (as expected). I tried adding a class scoped variable and to set up the calling member name when instantiating the logger but that won't capture correct calling member.

I'm fairly new to C# so I might be missing the best way to do this - the way I see it I have to overload the Log function to add the [CallerMemberName] attribute but the standard logging call semantics (eg. LogCritical) won't use my overloaded function.

Of course I could just ditch my custom logging provider and write my own logging function which would be simpler but won't leverage the logging infrastructure provided by Microsoft. I know I can use Reflection but I'd prefer not to take the extra CPU hit as this software will run on very low end hardware.

Comment: Related :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258263/how-to-change-iloggerfacade-implementation-to-trace-caller-method-using-callerme

Comment: Have you considered an extension method on `ILogger`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Log function:

```
public void Log()
{
  var stackTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(1); // skip one frame as this is the Log function frame
  var name = stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name;
}
```

EDIT:

If you want to avoid reflection maybe:

```
using (_logger.BeginScope("name of method"))
{
    // log the stuff
}
```

Not sure about .Net Core but in normal .Net you could add this by using Aspect Oriented Programming to multiple methods fairly easy.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that earlier however this function has a different implementation in dotnet Core from what I can work out (it expects an exception and bool as parameters). 

Also StackTrace is an expensive function, like Reflection. Was hoping to use CallerMemberName which the compiler handles instead of at runtime.

Comment: @deandob you may want to mention what you have tried so people do not suggest it. You are asking for alternative suggestions so please state what you cannot work with.

Comment: Luk, good idea, using BeginScope to set a class scoped variable works, and is simple. Not sure how Aspect Orientated Programming would help - any pointers so I can learn? @CodingYoshi, you are right, I forgot to add in the original post.

Comment: Well postsharp has preview .net core support: http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/New-in-PostSharp-50-Preview-Support-for-NET-Core-10

Comment: This is not a comparable replacement for the [caller information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information). It is either reflection, that has a perf hit and incorrectly works with async (MoveNext instead of the expected method), or requires extra code (BeginScope) for every logger usage. Both options are runtime, and [caller information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information) is added at compile time.