# Microsoft.Extensions.Logging custom implementation, how to get the caller method name?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-5, .net-6.0

I'm in .NET 6, I implemented a custom `ILogger<TService>` (of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`).

Usually, when I implement a logger, I also get the caller method name with `[CallerMemberName]` attribute, for example:

```
public void LogInformation(string message, [CallerMemberName] string callerName = null)
```

I really don't understand how to get the same `[CallerMemberName]` with the `ILogger<TService>` interface. I checked for `EventId`, but it doesn't have that information.

```
// Dummy class, don't try this at home!
internal class CustomLogger<TService> : ILogger<TService>
{
    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
        => default;

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
        => true;

    public void Log<TState>(
        LogLevel logLevel,
        EventId eventId,
        TState state,
        Exception exception,
        Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        // TODO How to get the caller name?
        string callerName = "Log";

        switch (logLevel)
        {
            case LogLevel.Trace:
            case LogLevel.Debug:
            case LogLevel.Information:
            case LogLevel.Warning:
                Console.WriteLine(callerName + ": " + formatter(state, exception));
                break;

            case LogLevel.Error:
            case LogLevel.Critical:
                Console.WriteLine(callerName + ": " + formatter(state, exception));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a bult-in way to get it without `reflection` or other expensive methods?

---

Why I need to implement a custom `ILogger<T>`?

1. I use two external libraries which I don't control that want and `ILogger<T>` implementation (so I can't force them to call an extension method),
2. I need to store the logs by my own storage and there aren't any providers for what I need in this case

Why I need to add the `CallerMemberName`?

- To enrich my logs. They are far more readable and informational with that information.

Comment: I can't comment so, an answer it is.
Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41786529/2502983) ?

Comment: What is your *actual* question? Why do you implement your own custom logger? If the reason is to include the caller name, there's no reason to implement a logger. What you need is to enrich the log with the caller. You can't do that in a custom logger - at that point all the information is already collected and ready to be written out

Comment: If you google for ways to include caller info, a *very* common, easy and cheap solution is to create extension methods over `ILogger<T>` that have the `CallMemberName` attribute and pass caller info and forward that information to their logger argument

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the reasons are two: 1. I use two external libraries which I don't control that wants and ILogger<T> implementation (so I cant' force them to call the extension method), 2. I need to store the logs by my own

Comment: The point remains that you need to look for ways to enrich the log event, not change the logger. If you use a library like Serilog, enriching is relatively easy. .NET Core's logging doesn't have an explicit enricher endpoint. A *lot* of applications use Serilog integration with .NET Core logging. Few people add caller info after the fact though, because walking the stack frame is both expensive and easy to get wrong

Comment: Why do you want to include the method name in every log message? Logging isn't tracing. Exceptions contain stack traces because simply throwing an exception is costly and a stack trace will make solving the problem a lot easier.

Comment: Honestly I'm tired about you asking "why". I want to do it for my own reasons, that's not important to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

I really wish I could edit my own "comment", it was an answer converted to a comment, but, here it goes.
From the [answer I shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41786529/2502983)

```
public void Log()
{
  var stackTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(1); // skip one frame as this is the Log function frame
  var name = stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name;
}
```

or avoiding reflection

```
using (_logger.BeginScope("name of method"))
{
    // log the stuff
}
```

credits to the original answer

Comment: `new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(1)...` AFAIK this is very expensive and unreliable operation cause "correct" method can be actually optimized away.

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote in the question I'd like to avoid using reflection or similar expensive methods. I was wondering if there is a builtin method within the ILogger<T> interface.

Comment: @FrancescoBonizzi that way is to use extension methods with `CallerMemberName`. When that happens, the compiler itself generates the string value at the call site. Without that, any lower-level method has to check the stack trace to find out who the caller is. With async methods and lambdas, the top-level method may be completely different than what was expected

Comment: I understood @PanagiotisKanavos, but the point is that I don't have control over who calls ILogger<T> implementation because it is used in other libraries, and I was wondering if there is a way to get the caller method name information by myself in my implementation that will be injected.

Comment: Then, my suggestion is the answer @PanagiotisKanavos gave on the comment to your question, use a more versatile Logging library like Serilog

Answer (score 1):

you could add/overload the logging functions (extension methods) to the static LoggerExtensions class and in your Log function check for the beginning of the formatted message, split..

```cs
public static class LoggerExtensions
{
    public static void LogCritical(this ILogger logger, string? message, [CallerMemberName] string callerMemberName = "")
    {
        logger.LogCritical("cmn_{message}_{caller}", message, callerMemberName);
    }
        
    public static void LogDebug(this ILogger logger, string? message, [CallerMemberName] string callerMemberName = "")
    {
        logger.LogDebug("cmn_{message}_{caller}", message, callerMemberName);
    }
```

in `Log<TState>`:

```cs
string message = formatter(state, exception);
string caller = "";
            
if (message.StartsWith("cmn"))

    string[] messageSplit = message.Split(new char[] {'_'});
    message = messageSplit[1];
    caller = messageSplit[2];
}
```

(unfortunatelly you cannot directly access `TState state` in `Log<TState>` since it's internal, thus the split workaround)